# Forward packet between containers using iptables

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, docker

I'm currently doing some experiment with OpenvSwitch and Docker containers. I have a simple setup of containers A,B,C running Alpine image with added iptables. All 3 containers are connected to a single OVS on my host machine.

I have set up a flow rule inside the OVS so that every packet that is sent by container A to container C has to go through B. This includes UDP,TCP,ICMP packets, etc. Those packets seem to reach container B, but they are simply dropped there without being forwarded back to the OVS. I understand that this is the normal behaviour of a host machine, but how do I enable packet forwarding between containers so that every packet from A to C will first be examined by B, and sent back to the OVS before reaching C? My knowledge of iptables is limited so anything that points me to the right direction is appreciated. :)

Comment: Being curious: what about replies? Will they go directly from C to A? And what do you mean by "examined": captured? filtered? altered via userspace?